# Which version of Terraria has more items?

Tags: terraria

I need to know which version of Terraria has more items; PC or PS3?  I have bought the PS3 version of Terraria, but I'm wondering if I should get the PC version, since it may have more items.

Comment: I only know of console-exclusive items, but not of PC-exclusive ones. However, the console version has bugs that are not present in the PC version, such as gathering too many *Platinum Coins* will turn them into *Fallen Stars*, which is bad, considering that *Fallen Stars* are much easier to gather and are worth **a lot** less than *Platinum Coins*.

Comment: Right now console has more items, but PC is going to get an updated (no release date for it yet though) that adds an extreme amount of items.

Answer (score 3):

Right now the console version has [a number of exclusive items](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Console_Terraria), although there is some information on an [update](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/1-2-preview.100509/) coming for PC in the near future. Because the game updates aren't parallel it's impossible to say which one is better in terms of content, but that's the state of things right now.

Answer (score 2):

There are 1866 items in Terraria 1.2.1.2 on the PC, 1264 of which are exclusive to the PC. According to the amount of console-only items [found in this wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/List_of_items), the total amount of items in the console version is 627. PC is the one to have more *at the moment*.

Answer (score 0):

There are some [really solid mod packs](http://www.terrariaonline.com/forums/client-server-mods-tools.51/) for Terraria on the PC. Counting mods the PC wins easily. Not counting mods the PS3 wins easily.